# cURL + Java -- CPAS Request -- Suggestion Please

Tags: java, http, curl, httprequest

**Explination**
I am working on a Java App that sends a text message via a CPAS API (Similar to Tweepy). I am using CURL to request the message send. The request from Java seems to be sent but I am getting a 401 code. I'm assuming there is an issue with the encoding of my Authentication for the request. The code is as follows:

```
    URL url = new URL("https://api.zang.io/v2/Accounts/ACe1889084d37de951ef064200aecbe4b2/SMS/Messages");
```

String auth = AUTH + ":" + TOKEN;

```
    String encodeedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(auth.getBytes());
    HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    http.setRequestMethod("POST");
    http.setDoOutput(true);
    http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodeedAuth);
    
    String data = "From=+14132698029&To=17817381451&Body=New Test";

    byte[] out = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    OutputStream stream = http.getOutputStream();
    stream.write(out);

    System.out.println(http.getResponseCode() + " " + http.getResponseMessage());
    http.disconnect();
```

"""

Comment: What's your specific programming question?

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP 401 response is commonly an HTTP endpoint authorization failure. The best way to see why your auth credentials are failing is to capture the request/response pair in transit (at the receiving end would be optimal) and then compare that request/response pair to one that works.